# Storing a python list as a scene variable

Tags: python, interface, add-on, blend-files

What is the best practice way to store a python list defined in an addon as a scene variable in Blender?

Using

```
global mylist
```

doesn't work because the variable is not a Blender-specific type and therefore not saved after a button click operation completes.  I would like the list to exist in the Blender environment so that I can access it from future function calls.

My current solution is to use Blender Collection Properties, with my own wrapper functions, but this seems kind of excessive:

```
bpy.types.Object.CP_list = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.PropertyGroup)

def CollectionProperty2list(CP, numerical = False):
    new_list = []
    if (numerical):
        for elt in CP:
            new_list.append(float(elt.name))
    else:
        for elt in CP:
            new_list.append(elt.name)
    return (new_list)

def list2CollectionProperty(mylist, CP):
    CP.clear()
    for elt in mylist:
        CP.add().name = str(elt)  # stores string for numerical or string input
    return()
```

storing:

```
list2CollectionProperty(py_list, obj.CP_list)
```

retreiving:

```
py_list = CollectionProperty2list(obj.CP_list)
```

Comment: What seems more practical to me would be a way to store an entire python list to a single Blender variable, rather than assigning each element separately, and then retrieving each element separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Storing a list as an ID property**

```
# assign a list
>>> C.scene["mylist"] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> C.scene['mylist']
<bpy id property array [6]>
# save file, reopen
>>> C.scene['mylist'].to_list()
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This will work for lists where all items are of the same type: strings, ints,  floats or booleans (booleans as ints).

Could try using your methods above as [getters / setters](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#get-set-example)  ... but I don't think `get` is available for `bpy.props.CollectionProperty`.

Comment: So simple!  Also works for objects, without having to use the Blender properties:  ob["mylist"] = py_list